# Column of text type returned but not displayed in laravel 5.4 edit form

Tags: html, forms, laravel-5.4

Working on an edit form, i'm able to display all data from my query except the one for addresses. Looked up my code and it looks good but still the old data from database isn't showing in that field. Could this be the way am calling it since its of text type?

Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $customer= Customer::findOrFail($id);

    dd($customer->contact_address);

    //return view('customers.edit', compact('customer'));
}
```

dd($customer->contact_address) returns

```
"18B Harvey Street, Crosstour Estate. Ikeja, Lagos."
```

edit form field

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="contact_address" class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea id="contact_address" type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_address" value="{{ $customer->contact_address }}" row="3" required autofocus></textarea>
     </div>
 </div>
```

How do make it display like the other field are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is not a textarea attribute, output the address between the textarea tags:

```
<textarea>{{ $customer->contact_address }}</textarea>
```

Alternatively, I believe `textarea` elements support the `placeholder` attribute, so:

```
<textarea placeholder="{{ $customer->contact_address }}"></textarea>
```

Comment: Using the first option fixed it. If the placeholder attribute is used, then it won't be possible to update the content. Thanks